# Vue Validator only after change / blur / submit

Tags: vue.js

I'm using Vue for the first time, with [Vue Validator](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-validator/). Here is an example of my code:

```
<label for="first_name">First name:
    <span  v-if="$validation1.first_name.required" class="invalid">Enter your first name.</span>                            
    <input id="first_name" placeholder="e.g. Christopher" class="" v-validate:first_name="[&#039;required&#039;]" v-model="first_name" name="first_name" type="text">
</label>
```

The only issue at the moment is that when I land on the page with my form, the whole thing is covered in errors. Is there a way I can suppress the errors and only show them on input blur / form submit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Argh, the Google-able word isn't about `blur`, or on `submit` – its about `timing` and `initial`:

http://vuejs.github.io/vue-validator/en/timing.html

```
<input id="first_name" initial="off" placeholder="e.g. Christopher" class="" v-validate:first_name="[&#039;required&#039;]" v-model="first_name" name="first_name" type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add .dirty or .touched to your validation

```
    <label for="first_name">First name:
    <span  v-if="$validation1.first_name.required && $validation1.first_name.touched" class="invalid">Enter your first name.</span>                            
    <input id="first_name" placeholder="e.g. Christopher" class="" v-validate:first_name="[&#039;required&#039;]" v-model="first_name" name="first_name" type="text">
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with a similar problem. I had to have an initialized variable for the input `name: ""` but I also wanted to have a `required` attribute in element.

So I add `required` when the event onblur occurs.

`<input name="name" type="number" v-model="name" @blur="addRequired" />`

```
const app = Vue.createApp({
    data() {
        return {
            name: ""
        }
    },
    methods:{
        addRequired: function(event){
            event.target.setAttribute("required", true);
        }
    }
});
```